# missing the "add fingerprint" option for SHA1 in Firebase settings

Tags: firebase, sha1

I've been working on this project for the past couple of months.

It's written in JavaScript, have used very little JAVA in Android Studio and using Firebase as server and DB.

I want to give the user the option to signup through Google. One of the steps required for that is to add the SHA1 code generated by the Android Studio in the project's settings in Firebase.

For some reason I just don't have that option in Firebase's settings.[this is how my settings page look in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrH6g.jpg)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You should add an android app for that.

If you want to use google signin in progressive web app you can use normal web authentication (no need for android key fingerprint) but then you must change your webview user-agent string (otherwise google will block the login attempt).

Comment: I have an active android app

Comment: On firebase or on play store? The screen you've sent is for firebase webapp